# How could I integrate $\int_0^\infty \sin(k|x|)/k^2\,dk$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration

Does anybody know how to evaluate this integral?

I have
$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(k|x|)}{k^2}\,dk$ 
and I tried several contour integration in the complex plane like the key-hole.

I think I'm doing something wrong when I try to calculate the limit on the little circle surrounding $z=0$, but I can't figure out what and how to solve the integral.

Thanks for answering!

Comment: Are you sure that your integral does converge on the given interval?

Comment: Apparently not, maybe it's assumed not to converge and take some limit for $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$

Comment: It might converge as a distribution in $x$.

Comment: @AlessandroD. The integrand behaves like $1/k$ around zero, that's not an integrable singularity.

Comment: In support of the previous comments: are you sure this is the correct expression? Maybe it's $\sin k |x|/k$ instead?

Comment: Maybe it's my bad and I did some mistakes in getting this expression